# SQL Sum Column Between Two Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sum, between

I have problem to sum price column between two dates in SQL Server.

I have query like this :

```
SELECT
    OSLP.SlpName as Salesman,
    CAST(OINV.DocTotal as float) as Achiev,
    OINV.TaxDate
FROM 
    OINV
INNER JOIN 
    INV1 ON INV1.DocEntry = OINV.DocEntry
INNER JOIN 
    OSLP ON OINV.SlpCode = OSLP.SlpCode
INNER JOIN 
    OITM ON INV1.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode
INNER JOIN 
    OMRC ON OITM.FirmCode = OMRC.FirmCode
INNER JOIN 
    OCRD ON OINV.CardCode = OCRD.CardCode
WHERE
    OSLP.SlpName LIKE '01-2 Ika' 
    AND OINV.TaxDate BETWEEN '20160804' AND '20160806'
GROUP BY
    OSLP.SlpName, OINV.DocTotal, OINV.TaxDate
```

The result of the query above is like this :

[image]

I have also added SUM on "CAST(OINV.DocTotal as float) as Achiev" like this :

```
CAST(sum(OINV.DocTotal) as float) as Achiev
```

But, it returns wrong result :

[image]

The correct result of the Achiev column on the dates should be **`4906230`**

Many thanks for the help!

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**
I have solved the problem. It just add distinct to the SUM query, because there is a duplicate of data in my query.

Query :

```
SELECT
  OSLP.SlpName as Salesman,
  sum(CAST(INV1.Quantity as float)) as Qty,
  sum(DISTINCT CAST(OINV.DocTotal as float)) as Achiev
FROM 
  OINV
INNER JOIN 
  INV1 ON INV1.DocEntry = OINV.DocEntry
INNER JOIN 
  OSLP ON OINV.SlpCode = OSLP.SlpCode
INNER JOIN 
  OITM ON INV1.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode
INNER JOIN 
  OMRC ON OITM.FirmCode = OMRC.FirmCode
INNER JOIN 
  OCRD ON OINV.CardCode = OCRD.CardCode
WHERE
  OSLP.SlpName LIKE '01-2 Ika' 
  AND OINV.TaxDate BETWEEN '20160804' AND '20160806'
GROUP BY
  OSLP.SlpName
```

it returns :
[image]

Thanks to everyone who has helped me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is with group by .. remove OINV.DocTotal from group by and do sum like below

```
SELECT
OSLP.SlpName as Salesman,
sum(CAST(OINV.DocTotal as float)) as Achiev,
OINV.TaxDate
FROM OINV
  INNER JOIN INV1 ON INV1.DocEntry = OINV.DocEntry
  INNER JOIN OSLP ON OINV.SlpCode = OSLP.SlpCode
  INNER JOIN OITM ON INV1.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode
  INNER JOIN OMRC ON OITM.FirmCode = OMRC.FirmCode
  INNER JOIN OCRD ON OINV.CardCode = OCRD.CardCode
WHERE
OSLP.SlpName like '01-2 Ika' And OINV.TaxDate between '20160804' and '20160806'
GROUP BY
  OSLP.SlpName,
  OINV.TaxDate
```

Comment: i've tried query above, but its display incorrect query result. The screenshot is in my question above, on the line "wrong result"

Comment: Sory for very very slow response. The problem is solved now. I just added "DISTINCT" to "sum(CAST(OINV.DocTotal as float)) as Achiev" like this  "sum(DISTINCT CAST(OINV.DocTotal as float)) as Achiev".

Comment: Thank you for your help Sandeep :D

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to display sum of DocTotal against each seales man and also wanted to split it by TaxDate ,
use the following script

```
SELECT
OSLP.SlpName as Salesman,
CAST(sum(OINV.DocTotal) OVER(PArtition by OSLP.SlpName Order by   OINV.TaxDate) as float) as Achiev
OINV.TaxDate
FROM OINV
  INNER JOIN INV1 ON INV1.DocEntry = OINV.DocEntry
  INNER JOIN OSLP ON OINV.SlpCode = OSLP.SlpCode
  INNER JOIN OITM ON INV1.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode
  INNER JOIN OMRC ON OITM.FirmCode = OMRC.FirmCode
  INNER JOIN OCRD ON OINV.CardCode = OCRD.CardCode
WHERE
OSLP.SlpName like '01-2 Ika' And OINV.TaxDate between '20160804' and '20160806'
```

If you wanted to display sum of DocTotal against each seales man 
use the following script.

```
SELECT
OSLP.SlpName as Salesman,
CAST(sum(OINV.DocTotal) as float) as Achiev
FROM OINV
  INNER JOIN INV1 ON INV1.DocEntry = OINV.DocEntry
  INNER JOIN OSLP ON OINV.SlpCode = OSLP.SlpCode
  INNER JOIN OITM ON INV1.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode
  INNER JOIN OMRC ON OITM.FirmCode = OMRC.FirmCode
  INNER JOIN OCRD ON OINV.CardCode = OCRD.CardCode
WHERE
OSLP.SlpName like '01-2 Ika' And OINV.TaxDate between '20160804' and '20160806'
GROUP BY OSLP.SlpName
```